# VMWare ESXi configuration corrupted on every boot

Tags: vmware-esxi, configuration

I've got a problem with configuration appearing as corrupted every time we restart our ESXi server, we get a PSOD and stops booting during the initialization process.

This is a test environment, however needing to restore the configuration every time we boot is getting to be a bit of a pain.

ESXi 5.5 has been installed on a 32GB AData USB flash drive, and runs normally once the configuration has been set up (the VMs are on a networked iSCSI), but for some reason on a normal shutdown we get the PSOD on boot.

Any ideas I can try to get it to not corrupt the configuration data on shutdown?

Comment: What kind of corruption is occurring?  Is the drive gone?  Is the Partition Table missing?  Does the corruption occur after shut down but is not corrupt beforehand (test it).  Have you tried using different flash drives, or different USB ports?  Have you tried installing ESXi onto an old fashioned SATA drive?

Comment: Are you using 100% HCL-compliant hardware? if not then you're in the wrong place, read our help pages.

Comment: Is ESX giving you the error? Or are the guest VMs giving you the error?

Comment: Not wanting to sound mean, but try with a more brand name flash drive?

Comment: Gettting the error on the ESX Terminal itself, as far as the other suggestions regarding what kind of corruption, etc... I'll have to test it, which will likely be this weekend...

Comment: Test it?  I wouldn't bother with that, just ask here and everything will get fixed...